# Write, execute and delete batch file

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, delete-file

I want a batch file to write another batch file to every sub directory, run the batch file and then delete it. The problem comes when writing a lot of information within the for loop. Is there any more effective way other than to chain &&? Also I am not sure whether writing commands to a batch file would screw up the batch file as it runs?

```
for /D /R "%cd%" %%d IN (*) do set thing=%%~nd && echo @ECHO OFF>%%d\Desktop.bat && call %%d\Desktop.bat && del /Q %%d\Desktop.bat
```

Comment: Why don't you get the batch file to perform the commands?  I don't think you have fully explained the aim.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like (untested):

```
for /D /R ... IN ... DO CALL :PROCESS %%d
GOTO END

...

:PROCESS
set thing=%~n1
echo @echo off>%1\Desktop.bat
call %1\Desktop.bat
del /q %1\Desktop.bat
GOTO :EOF


...

END:
... etc ...
```

Comment: I thought about using GOTO but I wasn't sure if you could return back within the for loop?

Comment: To return back, you should use "CALL :LABEL" followed by "GOTO :EOF" as shown in the sample.